# Need help to hide the ego_bar in facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, greasemonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Supprimer les suggestions d'amis sur facebook
// @namespace   facebook
// @description Supprimer les suggestions d'amis sur facebook
// @include     *.facebook.com
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
// ==/UserScript==

jQuery(function(){ $("#pagelet_ego_pane_w").remove() });
jQuery(function(){ $(".ego_column").remove() });
jQuery(function(){ $(".ego_unit_container").remove() });
//alert ("supprimé ?");
```

None of these lines worked. I am using this in greasemonkey.

Please see screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJd8u.jpg

Comment: Did you try $("#pagelet_ego_pane_w").hide() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`waitForKeyElements()`](https://gist.github.com/2625891). Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Supprimer les suggestions d'amis sur facebook
// @namespace   facebook
// @include     http://www.facebook.com/*
// @include     https://www.facebook.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

function removeEgoPane (jNode) {
    jNode.remove ();
    unsafeWindow.console.log ("Removed");
}

waitForKeyElements ("#pagelet_ego_pane_w, #pagelet_ego_pane", removeEgoPane);
```

---

**Important:**

1. Only some pages have the `#pagelet_ego_pane_w` div, and the script works perfectly on those.  But, most pages put the ego bar in a `#pagelet_ego_pane` div.  Hence the changed selector in the code above.

   If the ego bar returns, check that it's still in one of those 2 nodes.
2. Do not `.hide()` the div; that just lets Facebook unhide it and also run slow JS against it.  Better to remove those nodes if they are unwanted.

Comment: Yes, `waitForKeyElements` requires jQuery.  But jQuery in Greasemonkey has no downside... It's installed once and runs from the local machine.

Comment: I'v been told that recent versions of jQuery didn't play fine with greasemonkey, that's why I was told to use an old "compatible" version.

Comment: Well, that didn't work :(. I thought the ego_pane disappeared but in reality, it hasn't been shown in the first place. I modified your script to change remove with hide, but it didn't work either :(

Comment: The script worked perfectly, I tested it before posting.  However, the div specified in the question is NOT the usual div for the ego bar. (I assumed that's what you wanted.)  I avoid Facebook, except for client support, but my tests show that the ego bar usually appears in `#pagelet_ego_pane`.  See the updated answer.  If something still remains, post a screen shot of it, as well as the URL of the offending page.

Comment: That information about jQuery versions has been obsolete for a long time.  Greasemonkey works well with later jQuery.  I personally have never had a problem with 1.7.2, which I use on dozens of scripts (and it's the latest stable release hosted by Google).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by subrikumarsao, the .hide() worked fine :)

> Did you try $("#pagelet_ego_pane_w").hide() ? – subirkumarsao 3 hours
>   ago

Answer (score 0):

`$("#pagelet_ego_pane, #pagelet_side_ads, .ego_column").remove();` works for me.

I have this wrapped in a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications).

```
var target = document.querySelector("body");
// console.log(typeof target);

if (target) {
 // create an observer instance

 var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

   // Get rid of ad column on right side of page
   $("#pagelet_ego_pane, #pagelet_side_ads, .ego_column").remove();

   // Get rid of sponsored links
   $("#contentArea .uiStreamSponsoredLink").parentsUntil("._5jmm").remove();
 }
}
```